# jquery checkbox select value condition

Tags: jquery

This is my checkbox and I send value to next page. If checkbox is selected this value should be 0 else 1. How to send this value?

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="c_orders" id="c_orders" <?php if($_REQUEST['c_orders']==1) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> />
```

and the script is:

```
<script>
    function exportconfirm() {
        var retrn = confirm('Do you want to export to excel format?');
        if (retrn == true) {
            var c_orders = $("#c_orders").val();
            date = "&start_date=" + start_date + "&end_date=" + end_date;
        }
        window.location = 'export.php?action=total_sales&c_orders=' + c_orders;
    }
    }
</script>
```

This is showed undefined.

Comment: _"If checkbox is selected this value should be 0 else 1."_ Then why did you set the value to 1?

Answer (score 1):

Returning the value doesn't do you much good, check if the box is checked and set the variable based on that instead :

```
function  exportconfirm() {
    if ( confirm('Do you want to export to excel format?') ) {
        var c_orders = $("#c_orders").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
            date     = "&start_date="+start_date+"&end_date="+end_date;

        window.location='export.php?action=total_sales&c_orders='+c_orders+date;
    }
}
```

You're not using `date` anywhere, guessing that should be concatenated on as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the "checked" attribute like so :

```
$("#c_orders").attr('checked'); // will return true or false wether the checkbox is checked
```